# Looking for interdisciplinary research topic

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, combinatorics, artificial-intelligence

TL;DR: Are there any areas that combine (1) statistics/ML, (2) computation theory, (3) set/type theory, and (4) real/functional analysis? I apologize if I did not accurately categorize the domains listed.

I am a CS+math undergraduate, and my introductory real analysis, computation theory courses have piqued my interests (especially constructing proofs and set theory).

I would like to start hoarding papers and books for reading during Thanksgiving break. The only field that combines...

1. theoretical statistics+ML
2. computation+algorithm
3. logic (type theory)
4. math analysis

... that I could think of was AI, but I am unfamiliar with the specific subtopics within AI and would like some direction/recommendation(i.e. what questions require use of the topics above to answer?).

Generally speaking, I would like to learn more heavy duty analysis, combinatorics, theoretical statistics while remaining in the computational sciences (if possible).

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not averse to algebraic topology, check out [Topological Data Analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_data_analysis). You'll find a good list of learning links [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813766/where-to-start-learning-about-topological-data-analysis). In particular, check out Afra Zomorodian's *Topology for Computing* book. For real world motivation, check [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20160715131336/https://www.ayasdi.com/technology/).